# Сомнительные случаи запятых

Tags: запятые

*Мы с женой уже чуть ли не до ругани дошли!
Принципиально разные позиции в вопросе постановки знаков препинания, особенно перед словом "что"...*

Перед вами 6 предложений, которые, как утверждают, написаны без ошибок (а в скобках уже я даю свой комментарий):
- Я просто давно себя ругаю за то что пишу длинные тексты, не разбивая их (запятая перед "что", т.к. это сложноподчинённое предложение с союзной частицей).
- Я уверена что там не нужно запятых (запятая перед "что", т.к. это сложноподчинённое предложение с союзной частицей).
- Потому что бывают предложения по стилистике не сочетающейся между собой (запятая перед "не", ведь это деепричастный оборот).
- Я знаю точно что там не надо запятой (запятая перед "что", т.к. это сложноподчинённое предложение с союзной частицей).
- Я и говорю это моё слабое место в русском языке (запятая перед "это", ибо это сложносочинённое предложение).
- Я и говорю - это моё слабое место в русском языке (эта версия тоже неверная, никаких тире тут не должно быть, нет ни перечисления, ни обобщения, ни прямой речи, это обычное сложносочинённое предложение, части которого должны быть разграничены знаком препинания "запятая").

**Нужны ли запятые в каждом конкретном случае?**

*Будем благодарны за комментарии, в особенности если кто-то доступно объяснит про постановку запятых.*

Comment: Я не уверен, что вы правильно поступили, объединив шесть разных  вопросов в один... В любом случае мне пришлось немного отредактировать под местный "формат" Сейчас попробую ответить по сузеству.

Comment: Господин Капитан, какой смысл Вы вкладываете в выражение "предложения по стилистике"?

Answer (score 3):

**Разбор двух вариантов:**

(1) Я и говорю, это моё слабое место в русском языке. (2) Я и говорю — это моё слабое место в русском языке.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), вторая его часть имеет изъяснительное значение.

Розенталь допускает **оба варианта оформления.**

**Запятая**

(1) Я и говорю, это моё слабое место в русском языке.

По Розенталю, основным знаком в БСП при изъяснительном значении является двоеточие, при этом в устной речи делается интонационное предупреждение (увеличенная пауза, неполное понижение голоса перед паузой). Однако в некоторых случаях двоеточие можно заменить запятой (делается небольшая пауза в речи).

**Примечание.** При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: **Слышу, земля задрожала** (Н.). http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_44.htm#ppp_3

**Тире**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

(2) Я и говорю — это моё слабое место в русском языке.

7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), **причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта:** Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.); Иногда мне думается — надо убежать (М. Г.); …Слышит — за кустами бузины девушка хохочет (М. Г.);  Они знали — будет буря;  [Ср. § 44, п. 3.]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разбор.

Answer (score 2):

**Я просто давно себя ругаю за то, что пишу длинные тексты, не разбивая их**
Вы правы. Запятая нужна, обоснование ваше принимается.

**Я уверена, что там не нужно запятых**
Запятая нужна, только "что" - ни в коем случае не частица. Здесь "что" - обычный союз.

**Потому что бывают предложения, по стилистике не сочетающИЕся между собой**
Запятая нужна, но не там где вы её предлагаете поставить. Здесь нет деепричастного оборота, есть *причастный* оборот.
Предложение поправил, в исходном виде оно диковато смотрится. Если ошибся, извините.

**Я знаю точно, что там не надо запятой**
Запятая нужна, "что" - не частица (см. выше)

**Я и говорю, это моё слабое место в русском языке**
Согласен, запятая нужна, если по минимуму. В отношении того, что это сложносочиненное предложение (БСС, надо полагать) - не уверен, что все так однозначно. ту можно и как прямую речь трактовать и даже как вводную конструкцию.

**Я и говорю - это моё слабое место в русском языке**
Вот тут я с вами не соглашусь в части обоснования.
Некая тенденция замены запятой на тире или постановки тире как дополнительного знака после запятой в подобных случаях существует, вопрос только  в том, насколько она вписывается в существующие правила пунктуации.

> эта версия тоже неверная, никаких тире тут не должно быть, нет ни
>   перечисления, ни обобщения, ни прямой речи, это обычное
>   сложносочинённое предложение, части которого должны быть разграничены
>   знаком препинания "запятая".

Про прямую речь уже сказал, она вполне возможна. Но тут другое... 
Если кто-то возьмется отстаивать тире взамен запятой, то явно не по причине перечисления или обобщения, но как признак *периода* речи или противопоставления.

*Не уверен, что такое обоснование найдет  понимание у редактора или корректора, но если автор будет сильно настаивать, что это именно авторский знак с подобным обоснованием придется согласиться.
Посмотрите, сколько всякого-разного может быть основанием для тире. https://therules.ru/dash/  (даю источник источник не самый академический, но подробный).*
*Причем минимум половина случаев отдается на откуп авторскому пониманию.*

Comment: Ох, спасибо, даже не ожидал, что всё так серьёзно.